# Setting position of Image control relative to screen

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently learning C# in my spare time but have become stuck. I am trying to move an Image control to a random position (Horizontal) on the screen, this is done based on the screen size and the size of the image control itself. Is it possible to set a Image.X and Image.Y position within C# and WPF?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use a `Canvas` panel for this, as it allows you to position children at X,Y coordinates.

```
<Canvas>
    <Image x:Name="myImage" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="200" />
</Canvas>
```

The `Canvas.X` and `Canvas.Y` are attached properties.  You can set them from code-behind like this:

```
myImage.SetValue(Canvas.Left, 200);
myImage.SetValue(Canvas.Top, 400);
```

Comment: @nblackburn yes, please see my edit.  They're attached properties so they work a bit differently.

Comment: I am using VS 2012 and only Canvas.Left, Right, Top, Bottom are showing up as valid options.

Comment: @nblackburn sorry ... my coffee machine is broken, this is what happens. :(  Use `Left` and `Top` instead of X and Y.

Comment: You can set these properties also through `Canvas.SetTop(myImage,100)` and `Canvas.SetLeft(myImage,200)`